# a links change size on click

Tags: css, vue.js, pagination

I have one problem here in code. My code works ok, but have problem in CSS.I made pagination in Vue but problem is link. On some links in pagination, links changes the size and get bigger dimension. For example, when I click on first number, or second links stay the same. But after I click on third or fouth link, my links change size and get bigger.
Thanks !

```
<template>
  <h1>Pagination</h1>
  <div class="pagination">
    
  <a class="hover"  @mouseover="isHovering = true" @mouseout="isHovering = false"  @click="changePageToParent(1); changePage(1);">First</a>
    <a class="hover" v-if="totalPage<=5"> <a class="hover" @mouseover="isHovering = true" @mouseout="isHovering = false" v-for="item in 5" v-bind:key="item" @click="changePageToParent(item); changePage(item)"> {{ item }} </a></a>

  <a v-else class="hover">
  <a v-if="lijeviOffset>=2" class="hover" >...</a> 

      <a class="hover" @mouseover="isHovering = true" @mouseout="isHovering = false" v-for="item in 5" v-bind:key="item" @click="changePageToParent(item); changePage(item)">
        <a class="hover" v-if="currentPage == 2">  {{ item+offset+1 }}  </a> 
        <a class="hover" v-else-if="currentPage == 1"> {{ item+offset+2 }}</a> 
                    <a class="hover" v-else>
                    <a class="hover" v-if="desniOffset == 8"> {{ item + 2 }} </a>  
                    <a class="hover" v-else-if="desniOffset == 9"> {{ item + 2}} </a>
                    <a class="hover" v-else>{{ item+offset }}</a>  
                    </a> 
      </a> 
        <a v-if="provjera" class="hover">...</a>
    </a>
  <a class="hover" @mouseover="isHovering = true" @mouseout="isHovering = false" @click="changePageToParent(totalPage); changePage(totalPage)">Last</a> 
 
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Pag',
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
      da: null,
      totalPage:7,
      perPage: 2,
      isHovering: false,
      isActive: false,

    }
  },
  props:  {
  total: Number,
  }, computed: {
    offset: function(){
    return this.currentPage-this.perPage-1;
    },
    provjera: function(){
          return this.currentPage+this.perPage<this.totalPage ? 1 : null
    },
    desniOffset: function () {
      return this.currentPage+this.perPage;
    },
    lijeviOffset: function () {
      return this.currentPage-this.perPage;
    },
  }, methods: {
    changePageToParent(id) {
      this.$emit('change-page-to-parent', id)
    },
    changePage(id) {
      this.currentPage = id
    },
    hoverToggle(subjectId, action){
    switch(action){
        case 'mouseOver':
            return this.hoveredSubjectId = subjectId;
        case 'mouseLeave':
            return this.hoveredSubjectId = "";
    }
  },
  toggleClass() {
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

body {
    color: blue;
}

.pagination {
  width:0 auto;
}

.hover a {
  margin:5px;
  background-color: red;
}



</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're adding a "hover" class instead of using the pseudo-class `:hover`?

After three or four clicks, do the links get bigger in their default state, on hover, on click?

If it's on click, you'll want to add styling with the `:active` pseudo-class. But remember to put your pseudo classes in this order, or they can override each other: `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`.

Edit: Image to explain my comment below: [image]

Comment: Only on click. When I click on third link in pagination list, and other links after that, links change size. I tried with :active pseudo class, but that doesnt work. When I implement active pseudo class, for example background-color property to blue, and click on link 3, it changes background color to blue for sec, and return background color to previous color.  This is strange behaviour, but I am novice in VueJS and maybe that VueJS and classes is a problem..

Comment: That's interesting. Does using the browser's inspector reveal anything? Including when you add the pseudo classes? (See image in my answer above.)